# Matlab: matrix made of vector forward decreasing

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am after altering a matrix, using vectorization and avoiding loops.

First I've got:

```
V = [x1 x2 x3 x4 x5]
```

I managed to create with `hankel` function:

```
M = [1 2 3 4 5; 
     2 3 4 5 0;
     3 4 5 0 0;
     4 5 0 0 0;
     5 0 0 0 0]
```

and with `repmat`:

```
A = [x1 x2 x3 x4 x5;
     x1 x2 x3 x4 x5; 
     x1 x2 x3 x4 x5;  
     x1 x2 x3 x4 x5; 
     x1 x2 x3 x4 x5]
```

And I would like to know how to combine `M` and `A` to get

```
[x1 x2 x3 x4 x5; 
 x2 x3 x4 x5  0; 
 x3 x4 x5  0  0; 
 x4 x5  0  0  0; 
 x5  0  0  0  0]
```

I don't think it's that hard but have not been able to figure it out!
Any help much appreciated. Thanks

edit:

Hankel (V) does the trick, thanks Wolfie.
I didn't specify that I'm after some gain in execution speed though (which is intrinsic to avoiding loops most of the time).

Answer (score 4):

You can do this pretty easily using indexing.

Leave your `V` as a row vector, but add a 0 to the beginning instead of using `repmat`:

```
V = [x1 x2 x3 x4 x5];
A = [0 V];           % add 0 to beginning of vector to account for 0s in output
M = hankel(1:5) + 1; % Get indices of A which correspond to location in output
output = A(M);

>> output = [x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
             x2 x3 x4 x5  0
             x3 x4 x5  0  0
             x4 x5  0  0  0
             x5  0  0  0  0]
```

Or don't generate `M` in the first place, and directly use `hankel`

```
V = [x1 x2 x3 x4 x5];
output = hankel(V)  

>> output = [x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
             x2 x3 x4 x5  0
             x3 x4 x5  0  0
             x4 x5  0  0  0
             x5  0  0  0  0]
```

Comment: Thanks Wolfie, yes I realize that using hankel directly from the beginning does the trick. No gain in terms of execution speed though compared to a loop (but I didn't specify in my initial question that it is what I'm after..).